# Send A Second Email to a Third Party on Checkout with Magento

Tags: email, magento, e-commerce, checkout

I'm facing a problem:

I'm configuring magento store, when a customer buy something, an email is send to him, but what I need is: beyond this email, another email, with diferent template must be send to another person with the data of the purchase. How to configure this ?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What I've done is:

I developed a webservice in c# that receive the OrderId, and send the email to the person I want. I call this webservice using ajax in the success method of magento.

Answer (score 2):

You can **configure** the data of order to be sent only with the **same** template. 
To do it - go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order and fill fields "Send Order Email Copy To" and "Send Order Email Copy Method".

However you can **program** Magento to send email with **different** template. To achieve it you must develop your custom extension that will:

- a) add necessary fields (ability to choose different template) to above mentioned System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order
- b) overload Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail() method to use different template for sending e-mail to third party

Comment: hum, what a bad new. But is OK, I'll develop something to send this email, thank you.